# Can I somehow get Google calendar to make a noise 5 mins before my meetings even if chrome is closed? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, google-calendar

Can I somehow get Google calendar to make a noise 5 mins before my meetings even if Chrome is closed? Can I maybe make a Windows app off the website that starts automatically when I reboot the computer, so notifications ring even if I forgot to start Chrome after rebooting it? Plus Chrome eats memory, I often close it. Ideally, for important meetings, since my computer is always hibernated but never off (I reboot it every few days though), it would be great if I could have the alarm go off even if computer is in hibernation.

Comment: Sync your Calendar to your phone and do it that way. Otherwise, Chrome needs to be open. Your machine sure will not tell you if it is hibernated.

Answer (score 0):

There are severals ways to achieve this, but the most reliable should be to sync your windows calendar and google calendar.

## Sync Windows calendar and google calendar

Just search for the calendar app of windows and configure your google-account.
[digitalunite explainig every step](https://www.digitalunite.com/technology-guides/computer-essentials/windows-10/how-set-email-and-calendars-windows-10)

## Create a scheduled task on login

If you don't want to sync your google-account to calendar (aka. slimed down outlook), you can configure an automatic windows task to start chrome after reboot.

1. Hit the Win-Button and enter *Task Scheduler*
2. Navigate the tree to the *Tasklibrary*
3. Create a simple task, give it a name and short description
4. Trigger -> On Login
5. Action -> Start program
6. Program: chrome.exe [URL if necessary]
7. Finish and test

This should start chrome every time your user logs in after an restart.

*The buttons/fields may have a differnet name, my Windows is on german and I've just translated them, please edit if necessary*

Comment: So no way to have notification without Windows calendar and with chrome off?